# Why are some Russian names Anglicised but not others?

Tags: names, transliteration

For example, we speak of "Peter" the Great, "Nicholas" II, and "Joseph" Stalin, but no one ever spoke of "George" Gagarin, "Theodore" Dostoevsky, or "John" the Terrible. Why?

Comment: Peter the Great named the city he founded  *Saint Petersburg* (Санкт-Петербург) after the Dutch version of the name, so he presumably wouldn't object to having his name anglicised.

Comment: Apparently Peter the Great used the pseudonym "Peter Mikhailov" in Holland and London when travelling incognito (to the extent that one of the tallest men in Europe could do so).  But there is no simple rule: the historical Philip II, III, IV and V of Spain contrast with the current Felipe VI

Comment: Russia is a complicated country.  For long periods of time, the upper and ruling classes spoke Russian only to their servants and serfs.  To each other they spoke French.  Russian, to the upper classes was a lower class language.  Of course, the first generations of Norman aristocracy spoke French to each other and much of the English language was transformed.  Words for things common folk could not afford like 'chairs' are derived from French; anglo-saxon provides is with 'stool' and 'seat'.

Comment: It's traditional to anglicize names of some country's kings and emperors as well as popes and similar rulers, although it has become less common recently. You could investigate to discover more precisely how it works (Holy Roman Emperors are anglicized, Kaisers of the German empire not). Stalin is slightly different, as it's common for Greek Φ and less commonly Cyrillic ф to be romanised as "ph".

Comment: @PeterShor “would not have objected to having his name anglicised”* would be the correct tense in that sentence.